# Calculate the integral $\int_{\partial D} \frac{z+4}{z-4}\frac{e^z}{\sin z} dz$.

Tags: taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Take the rectangle $D = \{ z\in\mathbb{C};|x|\leq 2,|y|\leq 1\}$. I need to calculate the integral
$$\int_{\partial D} \frac{z+4}{z-4}\frac{e^z}{\sin z} dz.$$
The only singularity in this case is in $z=0$. I've tried using the residue theorem, but I just can't work it out. How do I handle this problem?

Comment: Hint: use the limit definition of residue and a nice limit comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the limit definition of the residue at a first order pole at $z=c$
$$
\text{Res}_{z=c}f(z)=\lim_{z\to c}(z-c)f(z)
$$
and the standard limit
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{\sin(z)}=1
$$
It is then rather straightforward to show that
$$
\text{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{z-4}{z+4}\frac{e^{z}}{\sin(z)}\right)=-1
$$
Alternatively, making a Laurant expansion about $z=0$ (using the geometric series to expand $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$), shows that
$$
\frac{z-4}{z+4}\frac{e^{z}}{\sin(z)}=-\frac{1}{z}+\mathcal{O}(1)\text{ , as z}\to\text{ 0}
$$
which of course yields the same result.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(z)=\frac{z+4}{z-4}e^z$ then you are integrating $\frac f\sin$. And\begin{align}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(z)}{\sin z}\,\mathrm dz&=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{f(z)}{\sin z}\right)\\&=2\pi i\frac{f(0)}{\sin'(0)}\\&=-2\pi i.\end{align}